# T-SQL Ticks to OHLC Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, forex

What is the best way to convert ticks data into OHLC using custom time span input, start date and end date, following query standards?

The stored procedure should have 3 parameters to pass:

- a time span,
- a start date, and
- an end date.

I need two scenarios (with a stored procedure for each): one without gaps when there are no records between the time range, and the second with gaps when there are no records between the time range.

---

Here is the data:

```
BigIntDateTime,    DateTime,                Ask,     Bid
20000530171000000, 2000-05-30 17:10:00.000, 0.93020, 0.93970
20000530171010000, 2000-05-30 17:10:10.000, 0.98020, 0.98970
20000530171030000, 2000-05-30 17:10:30.000, 0.92020, 0.92970
20000530171040000, 2000-05-30 17:10:40.000, 0.9020,  0.90970
20000530171336000, 2000-05-30 17:13:36.000, 0.93020, 0.93970
```

Time Span: 1min

Output for first scenario

- time span: 1min
- start date: 2000-05-30 17:10:00.000
- end date: 2000-05-30 17:13:36.000

```
Time,                    OpenAsk, HighAsk, LowAsk,  CloseAsk, OpenBid, HighBid, LowBid,  CloseBid 
2000-05-30 17:10:00.000, 0.93020, 0.98020, 0.90200, 0.90200,  0.93970, 0.98970, 0.90970, 0.90970
2000-05-30 17:13:36.000, 0.93020, 0.93020, 0.93020, 0.93020,  0.93970, 0.93970, 0.93970, 0.93970
```

Output for second scenario

- time span: 1min
- start date: 2000-05-30 17:10:00.000
- end date: 2000-05-30 17:13:36.000

```
Time,                    OpenAsk, HighAsk, LowAsk,  CloseAsk, OpenBid, HighBid, LowBid,  CloseBid 
2000-05-30 17:10:00.000, 0.93020, 0.98020, 0.90200, 0.90200,  0.93970, 0.98970, 0.90970, 0.90970
2000-05-30 17:11:00.000, 0.93020, 0.98020, 0.90200, 0.90200,  0.93970, 0.98970, 0.90970, 0.90970
2000-05-30 17:12:00.000, 0.93020, 0.98020, 0.90200, 0.90200,  0.93970, 0.98970, 0.90970, 0.90970
2000-05-30 17:13:36.000, 0.93020, 0.93020, 0.93020, 0.93020,  0.93970, 0.93970, 0.93970, 0.93970
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Due to many reasons (industry practice, performance, re-use, scaleability, ETL/integration needs et al), the best way is to routinely pre-process stream-of-quotes into *<_static_forever_>* OHLC **V**-Tables, for later re-use in quantitative models, pre-calculated for all needed TimeFRAMEs (both the industry common and the synthetic ones).

## SQL part for <*aVarTimeSPAN*> for both Scenario A & B

Then use a standard SQL query to `SELECT` just the required variable, user-defined time-span

```
SELECT * FROM aCurrenex_AUDUSD_M1
WHERE  aUTC_BarTimeSTAMP BETWEEN <_value1_> AND <_value2_>;
```

.

## A custom-defined, non-linear re-framing of Quotes ( aka ticks )

**Scenario.A** and **Scenario.B** make different re-framing of the `[Bid,Ask]` records "inside" the requested time-span.

Above defined sample of the DataSET does allow for multiple interpretations, how shall the OHLC be calculated in either of the scenario approaches.

What are correct Open/Hi/Lo/Close values for real-world sample like this, supposing time span is [ 2013.11.04-00:00:55.000,

```
YYYY.MM.DD HH:MM:SS.TTT  |Bid     |Ask
|          |             |        |
2013.11.04 00:00:53.843; 0.94582; 0.94554;
2013.11.04 00:00:59.500; 0.94575; 0.94551;
2013.11.04 00:00:59.234; 0.94582; 0.94551;
#----------|-------------|--------|-------------------------<aStandardM1BAR.EoB>
2013.11.04 00:01:02.750; 0.94582; 0.94554;
2013.11.04 00:01:02.793; 0.94582; 0.94551;
2013.11.04 00:01:08.937; 0.94582; 0.94548;
2013.11.04 00:01:09.968; 0.94580; 0.94548;
2013.11.04 00:01:11.984; 0.94573; 0.94548;
2013.11.04 00:01:12.390; 0.94573; 0.94545;
2013.11.04 00:01:12.434; 0.94573; 0.94542;
2013.11.04 00:01:34.500; 0.94581; 0.94542;
2013.11.04 00:01:38.703; 0.94581; 0.94541;
2013.11.04 00:01:38.796; 0.94573; 0.94541;
2013.11.04 00:01:42.031; 0.94572; 0.94541;
2013.11.04 00:01:47.343; 0.94582; 0.94547;
2013.11.04 00:01:48.546; 0.94582; 0.94561;
2013.11.04 00:01:48.551; 0.94575; 0.94555;
2013.11.04 00:01:50.843; 0.94570; 0.94542;
2013.11.04 00:01:50.940; 0.94570; 0.94546;
2013.11.04 00:01:51.546; 0.94568; 0.94538;
2013.11.04 00:01:51.359; 0.94570; 0.94540;
2013.11.04 00:01:55.859; 0.94570; 0.94546;
2013.11.04 00:01:55.937; 0.94563; 0.94543;
2013.11.04 00:01:57.359; 0.94564; 0.94543;
#----------|-------------|--------|-------------------------<aStandardM1BAR.EoB>
2013.11.04 00:02:05.078; 0.94563; 0.94543;
2013.11.04 00:02:06.562; 0.94564; 0.94543;
2013.11.04 00:02:08.812; 0.94572; 0.94550;
2013.11.04 00:02:15.359; 0.94572; 0.94549;
2013.11.04 00:02:15.078; 0.94572; 0.94547;
2013.11.04 00:02:32.178; 0.94563; 0.94540;
2013.11.04 00:02:32.432; 0.94564; 0.94540;
2013.11.04 00:02:33.359; 0.94564; 0.94538;
2013.11.04 00:02:34.031; 0.94564; 0.94535;
2013.11.04 00:02:39.218; 0.94564; 0.94537;
2013.11.04 00:02:41.343; 0.94559; 0.94535;
2013.11.04 00:02:46.906; 0.94559; 0.94529;
2013.11.04 00:02:46.978; 0.94559; 0.94532;
2013.11.04 00:02:51.640; 0.94559; 0.94529;
2013.11.04 00:02:55.500; 0.94560; 0.94529;
2013.11.04 00:02:56.578; 0.94582; 0.94552;
#----------|-------------|--------|-------------------------<aStandardM1BAR.EoB>
2013.11.04 00:03:01.046; 0.94582; 0.94555;
2013.11.04 00:03:03.968; 0.94585; 0.94555;
2013.11.04 00:03:04.734; 0.94583; 0.94555;
2013.11.04 00:03:09.562; 0.94581; 0.94536;
2013.11.04 00:03:10.718; 0.94568; 0.94530;
2013.11.04 00:03:10.968; 0.94561; 0.94530;
2013.11.04 00:03:11.562; 0.94566; 0.94537;
2013.11.04 00:03:13.718; 0.94568; 0.94539;
2013.11.04 00:03:14.218; 0.94568; 0.94538;
2013.11.04 00:03:14.750; 0.94569; 0.94538;
2013.11.04 00:03:15.953; 0.94569; 0.94540;
2013.11.04 00:03:16.437; 0.94570; 0.94540;
2013.11.04 00:03:21.359; 0.94575; 0.94545;
2013.11.04 00:03:23.796; 0.94573; 0.94542;
2013.11.04 00:03:29.203; 0.94570; 0.94540;
2013.11.04 00:03:29.875; 0.94567; 0.94540;
2013.11.04 00:03:34.859; 0.94572; 0.94550;
2013.11.04 00:03:36.062; 0.94574; 0.94550;
2013.11.04 00:03:36.359; 0.94574; 0.94548;
2013.11.04 00:03:36.671; 0.94574; 0.94546;
2013.11.04 00:03:36.915; 0.94575; 0.94550;
2013.11.04 00:03:37.578; 0.94578; 0.94550;
2013.11.04 00:03:37.781; 0.94576; 0.94546;
2013.11.04 00:03:37.896; 0.94573; 0.94541;
2013.11.04 00:03:38.532; 0.94571; 0.94540;
2013.11.04 00:03:39.765; 0.94570; 0.94540;
2013.11.04 00:03:39.803; 0.94568; 0.94540;
2013.11.04 00:03:58.500; 0.94573; 0.94548;
#----------|-------------|--------|-------------------------<aStandardM1BAR.EoB>
2013.11.04 00:04:08.375; 0.94575; 0.94548;
2013.11.04 00:04:09.734; 0.94580; 0.94560;
2013.11.04 00:04:14.784; 0.94592; 0.94564;
2013.11.04 00:04:14.987; 0.94587; 0.94563;
2013.11.04 00:04:14.996; 0.94587; 0.94566;
2013.11.04 00:04:15.062; 0.94574; 0.94552;
```

Comment: thank you for reply but unfortunately it is not a case

Comment: @Paul Which of the given features of your ProblemDEFINITION was not solved this way? TickDataSET is always either a `<static>` or a `<stream_of_statics>` so pre-processing both the format ( `<BigIntDateTime>` -> `<Time>` incl. the ZULU offset time adjustments ) and generating / updating multi-TimeFRAME static tables with OHLC ( + also Volume ) fields is both an industry standard and a performance must-do. `SELECT` meets the given requirement to get variable time-span. So, Paul, where is the reason, you feel your case is not solved?

Comment: @Paul Speaking about gaps. Industry uses this term for bars, where there are missing any events from market ( quotes do not arrive as there is no PriceDOMAIN change ( neither Ask, nor Bid )). So your notation of "gaps" is a bit different, nevertheless, both of your **Scenario.A** & **Scenario.B** can get processed, as you have full control over the task and `<Volume>` ( a number of quote-arrivals during a given TimeFRAME `{M1|M5|M15|M30|H1|H4|D1|... }` Bar-duration ) allows you to process those periods of time, where no quotes arrived, with `SYNTH-DATA` as you declare for **Scenario.B** above.

Comment: I tired create range using in memory table as a helper but performance is unacceptable.

Comment: @Paul Understood.At least the `SELECT` makes your db-records available for further processing. Due to many reasons already noted above, RDBMS engine ( to which the SQL-process resorts as a resource for a serialised computation ) is the worst place to get results from. A distributed approach, being fed by the sub-set of records ( rather processed as stream, than a block of memory (as that can be pretty fat)) would be my option to proceed and process non-orthogonal & non-linear ( both in TimeDOMAIN and PriceDOMAIN ) OHLC+V just for the non-Bar-aligned start/end parts of the span from QuoteSTREAM